# Get list of records where not all of a certain field == true

Tags: sql

I have a table like this;

```
Fld1 Text
Fld2 Text
Fld3 Bool
```

The data might look something like this;

```
Fld1    Fld2    Fld3

1       1       T
1       2       T
1       3       T
2       4       T
3       5       T
3       6       F
4       7       F
```

So I want a query that gives me all the unique Fld1 entries where all of the Fld3's are T.

So in the above the result set should be;

1 and 2.  3 and 4 are omitted because not all their records have a T in them where as 1 and 2 have  all their records with True in them.

It's been years since I needed to do SQL and I'm struggling to get this.

Comment: err...shouldn't your results be 1 and 2, with 3 and 4 being omitted because they have atleast one 'f'?

Comment: Oops, thanks.  Modified

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tested example for Sql Server:

```
DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE (Fld1 VARCHAR(20), Fld2 VARCHAR(20), Fld3 BIT)

INSERT INTO @SomeTable( Fld1, Fld2, Fld3 )
VALUES  ( '1', '1', 1),
( '1', '2', 1),
( '1', '3', 1),
( '2', '4', 1),
( '3', '5', 1),
( '3', '6', 0),
( '4', '7', 0)

SELECT Fld1
FROM   @SomeTable
GROUP BY Fld1
having min(CAST(Fld3 AS INT)) = 1
```

This assumes that your Fld3 column is really a boolean (Bit).

It returns:

> 1
>   2

Comment: Not quite.  I need all the Fld1's that have all their records with True in them.  Had to modify question sorry.  Didn't downvote btw

Comment: But if the min for the group is 1, then none of them can be false (0).  (Again this assumes your boolean is of type bit (numeric) if you are storing strings of T and F, then it will not work.)

Comment: Replace that `MIN` with `MAX` and I will give you the vote up you deserve

Comment: @Alireza - But Max will include 3 in the result.  The OP does not want mixed true and false.

Comment: Oh I really saw that backwards! Think it's time to go to sleep

Answer (score 2):

Fld2 has no use then?  I think you can get by with a not in statement

```
select distinct fld1 
from atable 
where fld1 not in (select fld1 
                   from atable 
                   where fld3 = 'f')
```

Comment: I think this should work still...it will return all fld1 where there is not a fld1 = f entry.

Comment: oh geez...I omitted a from clause in my subquery. Thanks Vaccano, editted it in. @alireza - I should goto sleep too apparently.